# When and why do we use tf.reduce_mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In setting up the model I sometimes see the code:

```
# Scenario 1
# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=logits, labels=Y))
```

or

```
# Scenario 2
# Evaluate model (with test logits, for dropout to be disabled)
prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(prediction, tf.float32))
```

The definition of `tf.reduce_mean` states that it "calculates the mean of tensor elements along various dimensions of the tensor." I am confused about what it does in simpler language? When do we need to use it, maybe with reference to # Scenario 1 & 2 ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @meTchaikovsky  explained the general case of `tf.reduce_mean`. In both of your cases `tf.reduce_mean` simply works as any mean calculator i.e,. you're not taking mean along any particular axis of a tensor, you simply divide the sum of the elements in a tensor by number of elements.

Let's decode what exactly is happening in both the cases. For the both the cases assume `batch_size = 2` and `num_classes = 5`, meaning that there are two examples per batch.
Now for the first case, `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y)` returns an array of shape `(2,)`.

```py
>>import numpy as np
>>import tensorflow as tf
>>sess= tf.InteractiveSession()

>>batch_size = 2
>>num_classes = 5
>>logits = np.random.rand(batch_size,num_classes) 
>>print(logits)
[[0.94108451 0.68186329 0.04000461 0.25996487 0.50391948]
 [0.22781201 0.32305269 0.93359371 0.22599208 0.05942905]]
>>labels = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0]])
>>print(labels)
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]]
>>logits_ = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(batch_size,num_classes))
>>Y_ = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32,shape=(batch_size,num_classes))
>>loss_op = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_, labels=Y_)
>>loss_per_example = sess.run(loss_op,feed_dict={Y_:labels,logits_:logits})
>>print(loss_per_example)
array([1.2028817, 1.6912657], dtype=float32)
```

You can see that `loss_per_example` is of shape `(2,)`. If we take the mean of this variable then we can approximate the average loss for the full batch. Hence we calculate

```py
>>loss_per_example_holder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(batch_size))
>>final_loss_per_batch = tf.reduce_mean(loss_per_example_holder)
>>final_loss = sess.run(final_loss_per_batch,feed_dict={loss_per_example_holder:loss_per_example})  
>>print(final_loss)
1.4470737
```

Coming to your second case:

```py
>>predictions_holder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(batch_size,num_classes))
>>labels_holder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32,shape=(batch_size,num_classes))
>>prediction_tf = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions_holder, 1), tf.argmax(labels_holder, 1))
>>labels_match = sess.run(prediction_tf,feed_dict={predictions_holder:logits,labels_holder:labels})
>>print(labels_match)
[ True False]
```

The above output was expected because only the first example of the variable `logits` says that the neuron with highest activation (`0.9410`) is zeroth which is same as labels. Now we want to calculate the accuracy, which means we have to take the average of the variable `labels_match`.

```py
>>labels_match_holder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(batch_size))
>>accuracy_calc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(labels_match_holder, tf.float32))
>>accuracy = sess.run(accuracy_calc, feed_dict={labels_match_holder:labels_match})
>>print(accuracy)
0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, `tensorflow.reduce_mean` is the same as `numpy.mean`. It creates an operation in the underlying `tensorflow` graph which computes the mean of a tensor.

The most important keyword argument of `tensorflow.reduce_mean` is `axis`. Basically, if you have a tensor with shape `(4, 3, 2)` and `axis=1`, an empty array with shape `(4, 2)` will be created, and the mean values along the selected axis will be computed to fill in the empty array. (**This is just a pseudo-process to help you make sense of the output, but may not be the actual process**)

Here is a simple example to help you understand

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

one = np.linspace(1, 30, 30).reshape(5, 3, 2)

x = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[5, 3, 2])
op_1 = tf.reduce_mean(x)
op_2 = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=0)
op_3 = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)
op_4 = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(op_1, feed_dict={x: one}))
    print(sess.run(op_2, feed_dict={x: one}))
    print(sess.run(op_3, feed_dict={x: one}))
    print(sess.run(op_4, feed_dict={x: one}))
```

The first output is a number because we didn't provide an `axis`. The shapes of the rest of the outputs are `(3, 2)`, `(5, 2)` and `(5, 3)`, respectively.

`reduce_mean` can be useful when the target value is a matrix.